# Como eliminar o erro [objecto objecto] no celular?

Tags: apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Criei um app com HTML + JS + CSS , e faço uma requisição externa com Ajax.

Quando testo no meu computador ele funciona perfeitamente , mas quando empacoto e crio o .APK  ele dá a seguinte mensagem:

> ALERT [objecto objecto]

Como devo resolver isso?

Aqui esta o código de teste:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({

        url:"http://comprasemangola.ueuo.com/ver.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        data: "param=no",
        success: function(html){

            var DOM =jQuery('#DOM');
            console.log(html);
            jQuery.each(html,function(key,value){
                console.log(value);
                DOM.append("
                    <li><h3>"+value.item+"</h3><p>"+value.quantidade+"</p></li>");

            });

        },error:function(e){
            alert(e);

        }

    });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

    <h1>Compras em Angola</h1>

    <a href="index.php" data-rel="back" data-icon="carat-l" data-iconpos="notext">Back</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">Refresh</a>

</div>

<div style="text-align:center; background-color:#fff; min-height:32px;">

    <ul id="DOM"></ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**ver.php**

```php
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$sqlconn=mysqli_connect("","xxxx","texte2015","xxxx") or die(mysqli_error());
$dataquery = mysqli_query($sqlconn, "select * from produtos");
$arr = array();
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_object($dataquery)){

    array_push($arr, array("item"=>$r->item, "quantidade"=>$r->quantidade));
    # code...
}
print_r(json_encode($arr));

?>
```

link test
    http://comprasemangola.ueuo.com/

Comment: Precisaria de mais informações, mas pela mensagem você está retornando em JSON? Posta o seu código para entender melhor.